# Passar parâmetros usando o client do guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

Preciso consumir uma api, a passagem dos parâmetros são feitos dessa forma:

> https://api.typeform.com/v1/form/[typeform_UID]?key=[your_API_key]

Estou utilizando o guzzle para fazer a requisição.

Estou instanciando o client com a base url dessa form:

```
$client = new Client(['base_url' => 'https://api.typeform.com/v1']);
```

Eu queria passar os parâmetros `"/form"`, `"[typeform_UID]?key=[your_API_key]"`, utilizando o `$client->get()`. Se eu utilizo o `get(query=>[])` do guzzle ele não forma a url da forma que eu gostaria.

Alguém sabe alguma maneira de fazer isso, utilizando o `Client` com `base_url`?

Comment: Qual versão do Guzzle você instalou?

Answer (score 2):

A forma de definir o parâmetro padrão no `Guzzle` é usando `query`.

Veja:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://example.com/',
    'query'   => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);
```

Se você precisar usar outros parâmetros na *url* combinado com os parâmetros padrões que você quer definir, sugiro usar o método `Client::getConfig('query')`, combinando com os novos valores desejado, dessa forma:

```
$client->get('foobar', [
    'query' => $client->getConfig('query') + ['bar' => 'foo']
]);
```

Outra coisa que você precisa tomar cuidado é que o `Guzzle` tem umas regrinhas específicas para a "montagem" do `path` da sua `base_url`.

Se você colocar o `base_url` com a `/` no final, você não pode fazer uma requisição para `uri` colocando `/` no início. E se não colocar a `/` no final do `base_url`, aí já é o inverso, você precisa colocar a barra, sempre que fizer as requisições:

Exemplo A:

```
$cli = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => 'http://meusite.com/api/v1/']);
$cli->get('usuarios/list');
```

Exemplo B:

```
$cli = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => 'http://meusite.com/api/v1']);
$cli->get('/usuarios/list');
```